# How to perform an inclusion validation on a serialized attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, serialization

I have a model with an serialized attribute (array). I would like to validate the model only if each member of the array is included within the pre-determined options.

Example: 
I have a Person model which has a "mood" attribute. Users can have more than one mood, but each mood must be either 'happy', 'sad', 'tired' or 'angry'.

The model would be something like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  MOODS = %w[happy sad tired angry]
  # validates :inclusion => { :in => MOODS } 

  attr_accessible :mood
  serialize :mood
end
```

The commented validation doesn't work. Is there any way to make it work or do I need a custom validation?

(Note: I don't want to create a separate Mood model.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  MOODS = %w[happy sad tired angry]
  validate :mood_check
  attr_accessible :mood
  serialize :mood

protected
  def mood_check
    mood.each do |m|
      errors.add(:mood, "#{m} is no a valid mood") unless MOODS.include? m
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Check this documentation, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#inclusion. You don't have to create custom validations for that.

Comment: on serialized attributes, you do, otherwise the serialized value is checked for inclusion, which means mood = [tired, angry] will fail since MOODS.include?(mood) is false

Comment: Ah, i didn't see serialize method. Your answer should be right then.

Comment: thanks! So it seems the custom validation is strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving this here in case it helps anyone in the future - I've written a gem to better handle validating serialized attributes. You can just put those validations in a block syntax, the ways you might expect to:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  MOODS = %w[happy sad tired angry]
  attr_accessible :mood
  serialize :mood

  validates_array_values :mood, inclusion: { in: MOODS }
end
```

https://github.com/brycesenz/validates_serialized